# c# string builder - what is the best method to append strings into html string

Tags: c#, html, string, stringbuilder

i have a string that holds inside an html code,  what i need is to append another string that holds a table with the header that i want to add to the html.

now i need to navigate through the html string in order to place the header string right after the  tag.

in other place in the code i just did somthing like this:
 string headerTable = tableStart + watchCampaignLink + removeLink + printLink + tableEnd;

but now i need to find an index.

how can i find the index that i need to insert the header after him? cause i need to find the index of the  tag, and insert the header table inside of it and also to find the closing  tag in order to place there the footer table.

tnx

Comment: the string that contains the body is like this: <body dir="ltr" style="direction:ltr; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; background-color: #dddddd;">
how can i get the index of her last char?

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Format`, so if you have a string like below (noting the `{0}` format specifier at the location in which you want to insert your table):

```
string body = "<html> ... <div>{0}</div> ... </html>"
```

You can then form the complete html with:

```
string html = String.Format(body, table);
```